# Revision Control systems that support Single Checkout?

Tags: svn, version-control, tfs, visual-sourcesafe

I need to know which version control systems support "single checkout"? When I say single checkout (or single user checkout), I mean that only one person may have a file checked out at a time.

So far, I know of Visual Source Safe (VSS) and Team Foundation Server (TFS). Can you add any other systems to this list?

The reason I ask is that the big boss where I work is wary of introducing complexity to his small team and would prefer to avoid using a system where the "merge methodology" is prevalent. Right now they use VSS, but I am trying to convince them to get away from it since I know that it is roundly considered to be a really bad product which will eventually corrupt your data and lose your entire check-in history.

SVN with setting `svn:needs-lock` sounds like it might work. (See [Single user checkout in SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4014742/16387) ) Is there a way to have that setting system-wide?

Any other options?

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_revision_control_systems.  In the first table, look for "Merge or lock" under "Concurrency model".  There's several results.